# I can't resize my macintosh HD drive on os X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility

I have checked similar questions but didn't find an answer that worked.
I have a macbook pro late 2013 with OS X 10.9.5.

I have the OS X on the Macintosh HD drive (Mac OS Extended (Journaled)), windows on bootcamp and another 13 or so GB as "free space" (at the bottom)

On disk utility I don't even have the option to drag and change my Macintosh HD drive, and I can't seem to add the free 13GB to my main Macintosh HD doesn't matter what I do.

I did this in the past, and now just can't resize it at all - an image of my disk utility is attached. I just want to add the 13 GB of free space in the bottom to the main Macintosh HD drive. could you please help?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please add to your question the output of the following command from Terminal: `diskutil list`

Comment: @user3439894 , the diskutil list is right here: 
http://oi57.tinypic.com/opu5jr.jpg

Comment: The reason I asked for the output of `diskutil list` over the image you have in the OP of DU is I wanted to make sure you weren't using Core Storage, and you're not. As to my comment to scottishwildcat's answer all I'm will to commit to is to tell you that before doing anything make sure you have proper backups by which to recover in the event you have problems with this.  You'll need to boot the Mac from either an external device that's running OS X or if your Mac is capable booting using Internet Recovery you'll need to test whether or not the BOOTCAMP partition can be moved by Disk Utility.

Comment: Continuation from previous comment... I do not believe it can be moved however there is also the hidden Recovery HD between the Macintosh HD partition and the BOOTCAMP partition that will need to be dealt with.  The issue for me is I haven't done this after Apple started including the hidden Recovery HD so I can only go off memory and I believe the statements I made in my comment to scottishwildcat's answer to be true the last time I was in a similar situations sans the presence of the hidden Recovery HD between the Macintosh HD partition and the BOOTCAMP partition.

Comment: You need to use a tool that can move the BOOTCAMP partition to the bottom of the disk. For example there is [GParted](http://gparted.org). To be safe, could you post the output from the commands `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0`. These commands will not change your disk and may ask for your login password. I will like to confirm there are no errors in your partition tables. My guess for the missing slider is that your `Macintosh HD` partition is almost full. You can not make it bigger or smaller, therefore no slider appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot Camp using Apple's supported way is a bit rigid compared to other partitioning.

If you want to add the last 13 GB of your Hard Drive to the Boot Camp partition, you may want to try it from within Windows and see, if you can resize it there.

Trying to add the 13 GB to your Macintosh HD, you will need to know how partitioning works in general, which is independent of my very first statement of this answer.

Hard drives have a partition table, which stores where each partition starts. Since the starting point is an essential information, which holds the information of the size of the partition among other important features of that partition, no starting point of any given partition can be moved without having to destroy and rebuild this partition.

That being said: if you like to move down your Windows partition, you will have to move its start point, which in turn requires you to destroy and rebuild the Boot Camp partition.

**IMPORTANT:** You definitely want to have a backup of your Windows partition for the following unless you do not miss anything stored on the Windows partition.

Now with Apple's Boot Camp scheme in mind, you will need to remove the Boot Camp partition (using Boot Camp Assistant), which will expand the Macintosh HD by the space the Boot Camp partition took up (and maybe the extra 13 GB as well, but check this using Disk Utility afterwards and manually expand it, if necessary).  Then again, using Boot Camp Assistant, you recreate the partition with the extra 13 GB of space for the Macintosh HD.

There may be other tools to do the above, but neither do I know them by heart nor do I know of their reliability.  The essence is the same for any support program (supported or otherwise) that you cannot move a partition's starting point without destroying the partition first.

Answer (score 0):

What partition were you running from when you took that screenshot? If Macintosh HD is your boot partition, you may have to [boot into the recovery partition](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) in order to modify it.

Comment: While it's true that booting to the Recovery HD allows for some things that cannot be done while booted from the Macintosh HD nonetheless I do not believe the BOOTCAMP partition can be moved directly by DU even if booted from the Recovery HD or using Internet Recovery on applicable systems.  Haven't use Boot Camp in years so I don't remember all the details however IIRC what will need to be done is use [Winclone](https://twocanoes.com/winclone.php) to make a copy of the BCP that can then be restored after deleting the BCP and resizing the Macintosh HD to the size wanted, leaving space for BCP.

Comment: @scottishwildcat , that doesn't help. I can now indeed "control" the size of the macintosh HD partition, but cannot add the free space to it still. can't merge them.

Comment: @user3439894, really? I need to backup my windows, erase the entire bootcamp, resize the partition, and then to restore bootcamp? to add 13 free GB to my existing hard drive?